# Checked state for buttons Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have a checked state for group chexboxes in Bootstrap 3.0.2. [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons)

html:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="checkbox" name="123" data-toggle="button"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> 123
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="checkbox" name="456"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty"></span> 456
      </label>
    </div>
```

But `data-toggle="button"` doesnt works. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZktYG/)

How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: `data-toggle="button"` is really just there for bootstrap to find for auto initializing

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To actually check the input, you will need to add the checked property. This will not actually make it *appear* checked, but is important if you are using this in a form and actually want the input to be checked by default.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="123" data-toggle="button" checked>
```

To make it *look* checked (or pressed), add class `.active` to the `.btn` label wrapping it.

```
 <label class="btn btn-default active">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZktYG/2/

Not sure why `data-toggle="buttons"` isn't working. Could be related to this: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/8816

For now, you can achieve the same effect through JS by doing something like:

```
$('.btn-group').on('input', 'change', function(){
   var checkbox = $(this);
   var label = checkbox.parent('label');
   if (checkbox.is(':checked'))  {
      label.addClass('active');
   }
   else {
      label.removeClass('active');
   }
});
```

Comment: The ```data-toggle``` worked in my case, in meteor + bootstrap

Comment: So many places mention the "active" status needed on the button, but the additional tip to make sure "checked" is set on the input was PRICELESSLY helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

It's been a couple of years; however, I wanted to address the actual problem above of why the data-toggle="button" wasn't working.

The answer was to remove the data-toggle="button" on the <input>'s.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="checkbox" name="123"> 123
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input type="checkbox" name="456"> 456
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by making a custom attribute that housed whether it was active or not, then setting that value within JQuery's click event.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active check_button" id="check1">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked data-checked=true> Checkbox 1 (pre-checked)
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary check_button" id="check2">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" data-checked=false> Checkbox 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary check_button" id="check3">
    <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" data-checked=false> Checkbox 3
  </label>
</div>
```

You can see a working example of this within the fiddle,
https://jsfiddle.net/jeffbeagley/DTcHh/34024/

Comment: Boss! what if list of data is coming from backend? `active` on label that always works!