# How to change active color of bootstrap button group to have different color for each button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I press the `No` button I want it to turn red. I want the `Yes` button to behave the way it already does ie. limegreen when `active`. How do I do this?

Please see my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philphil/g1yazzvc/1/)

html

```
<div class="col-sm-5 btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-info">
        <input checked="checked" name="media_release" value="1" type="radio"> Yes
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-info active">
        <input name="media_release" value="0" type="radio"> No
    </label>
</div>
```

css

```
.btn-info.active {
    background-color: limegreen;
}
```

Comment: Sorry that doesn't seem to change the behavior of the fiddle. Is it just me?

Comment: Oh I see, it changes it to red when I hold down the button...No that is not what I want. I want the `No` button to turn red when active.

Comment: If you want the background to stay permanently then I don't think there is becuase **there is no parent selector**. That said, you may want to look through the Bootstrap documentation to see if they have a creative  solution.

Comment: It's not in the bootstrap documentation. Maybe I can use inline style?

Comment: From what I can see, from a quick google search, the only option is Javascript / jQuery

Comment: See- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19891400/checked-state-for-buttons-bootstrap

Comment: Maybe we are thinking 2 different results. What I wanted was exactly what the accepted answer did. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ahh..so the answer **was** in the documentation.as such...the original code was wrong. :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```css
.btn-info.active {
    background-color: limegreen;
}

.btn_red.active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-sm-5 btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-info">
        <input checked="checked" name="media_release" value="1" type="radio"> Yes
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-info btn_red">
        <input name="media_release" value="0" type="radio"> No
    </label>
</div>
```